# Using HTTTP Commands within Azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, https, devops

When completing a task, I want an HTTPs command to be sent to another program (API Topdesk) containing a number of values, including Status and time How do I configure that

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: It helped me in part, because it had to be done on a continuous basis, we made a webapp (Using a Repo) and linked it through a webhook. We are currently testing this

Answer (score -1):

You can use a [Command Line task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203) and perform your request using cUrl or the [Invoke-WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203) cmdlet. There is also a dedicated [Invoke REST API task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/http-rest-api?view=azure-devops&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203).